# ¿Por qué no entra el required en mi input?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un detalle en mi input, cuando pongo la etiqueta required no entra la validación de que el input se tiene que llenar, estoy trabajando con ajax, ya lo he intentado con javascript para hacer la validación pero no me queda, si alguien me pudiera orientar, por favor. dejo la parte de mi código

```
    <th><input id="error"  class="form-control" required  type="number" name="cantidad[]"  max='.$row['Cantidad'].'min="1"></input></th>';


<script>
  $(".btnconfirmar").click(function(){ 
     var arr = $('input[name="cantidad[]"]' ).map(function () {
     
         
      return this.value; // $(this).val()
      }).get();
      console.log(arr.filter(Number)[0]);
      var prod = $(this).data("prod");
      var retiro = $(this).data("retiro");
      var cantidad = cantidadactual - arr.filter(Number)[0];
      console.log(cantidad);
        data.prod = prod;
        data.retiro = retiro;
        data.cantidad = cantidad; 
        
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../funciones/test.php",
          data: data,
          success: function (response){          
            if(response){
       
 swal({
   
  title: "Cantidad restada",
  icon: "success",
}).then(function(isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
     
    location.reload();
 
  } else {
  }
});
}
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay diferencia entre los eventos asignados y el orden en que se ejecutan. Generalmente, el clic en botones se ejecuta primero y, después, se ejecuta el evento `submit`, que es donde el navegador verifica si los elementos requeridos fueron llenados o no.

En tu caso, estás escuchando clic en el botón y no das oportunidad a que el navegador haga las validaciones, lo adecuado es escuchar el evento `submit` del formulario.

Prueba este fragmento de código para que veas el comportamiento de ambos eventos.

```js
// Escuchando clic en botón
$('#btn1').on('click', e => {
    // Esto evita que se envíe formulario
    // No se dispara el evento submit y no se marcan campos con error
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('¡Clic!');
});

// Escuchando envío de formulario
$('#form2').on('submit', e => {
    // Esto evita que se envíe formulario
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('¡Submit!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
   Evento en botón:
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" value="0" min="1" max="10" required><br>
    <button type="submit" id="btn1">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form id="form2">
    Evento en formulario:
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" value="0" min="1" max="10" required><br>
    <button type="submit" id="btn2">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby , lo analizare